# systemd - How to create unit file for my java daemon?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I am trying to lanunch `java daemon` when system start in `Ubuntu 18.04`.

I see that in `Ubuntu 18.04`, `systemd` is used. so If I want to launch daemon like `/etc/init.d/myservice start`, I should create `systemd unit file`.

DigialOcean kindly made this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files), but It has many parts.

What would be the parts that make jobs done? 
Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jcderr/49b7ee3fc0ae689e7e2d From this gist, using 'ExecStart' in unit file seems to be OK.

Comment: Is the reason for your question that you don't want to read the lengthy article, or is it that you don't understand a part of it? Why didn't you try to pick *any* unit file on your system that looks like doing a similar task, and then *try something* before asking for generic abstract help?